# How to install Laravel 4 profiler

Tags: laravel-4, profiler

I'm a Ubuntu/git/composer noob, and I'm trying to follow the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler#installation).

After running the `php artisan config:publish loic-sharma/profiler` command I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Profiler\ProfilerServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/epcr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 158
```

I'm assuming the problem is that I haven't downloaded the code, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Most packages require you to manually add service provider in **app/config/app.php**. There is an array of providers inside.
Some providers require also facade alias.

So take a look at documentation, if it is provider, then it should be documented.

e.g.

```
'Miro\JSONSuite\JSONSuiteServiceProvider'
```

Comment: Yeah, I added those just as the install instructions said.  At what point am I actually downloading the package thought?  Do I need to manually download it and put it some where?  If so where?

Answer (score 0):

Try running composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run `composer update` after I added the require to my composer.json file.  After that I had a few permissions I needed to update and it worked after that.